# Changing the orientation of a Win control in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I need to allow the user to rotate a control (the control inherits from a TextBox) in 90 degree increments so the text can be read from either side, or even upside down.

I'm guessing I could override the control's paint event and just paint it in the orientation that I want, but I'm just wondering if there's a quicker/built-in way?

This is a WinForms project.  Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Must the rotated text be editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a WinForms or WPF project?

In WinForms this is not easy to accomplish.  It is possible to do by overriding Paint or using a fake Image.  But likely this is not going to be worth your effort as their will be a lot of odd corner cases that will be missed.

In WPF this can be accomplished by applying a `RotateTransform` to a given object.  Here is the documentation on this type and their are many tutorials available online for this sort of thing.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it is WinForms and I'm required to have the ability to rotate (program requirements are: make a program to replace LabelView across the whole company).  This project should be in WPF, but company policy prohibits it.